# Inject service with global function

Tags: angular, typescript

In all my services I have 2 methods, handleErrors and ExtractData, this violates the DRY principle.

The two methods:

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();  
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleErrors(error: any): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.throw(error.json(););
  }
```

I want make those methods public and move them to a service which I then would inject to all my services and thus going from:

```
  getFoo(): Observable<IFoo[]> {
    return this._http.get(FooApi)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrors);
  }
```

too:

```
  getFoo(): Observable<IFoo[]> {
    return this._http.get(FooApi)
      .map(this._helperService.extractData)     //<--
      .catch(this._helperService.handleErrors); //<--
  }
```

The error I receive on `.map(this._helperService.extractData)` is:

> Argument of type '(res: Response) => {}' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => {}'.   Types of
>   parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>         Property 'body' is missing in type 'Response'.

I tried adding brackets() but then I receive:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

Why does it work when the method is in the same class?
How can I make it work when the method is in another class, or maybe there is a different approach I need to take?

Comment: Its not because of the class. It is because you are missing an import in the module that defines the shared service. Hint: there is a global variable named `Response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `import { Response } from '@angular/http';` to your helper service.

Currently the helper service uses the lib.dom.d.ts `Response` interface.